# jQuery return parameters

Tags: jquery

This could be a novice question, but here goes...

Why do we use data**.d** when we have to read data from a jquery **to** web-service **call**? 
What is the significance of the .d?

Is there any supporting documentation for the same?

Updated : comments in **bold**

Thanks,

Sashidhar Kokku

Comment: What is a jQuery web-service? jQuery is a client-side JavaScript library.

Comment: Are you talking about accessing other APIs with jQuery? This sounds like a yahoo thing to me.

Comment: I think he means 'read JSON from some URL/Context/etc'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ".d" is a security feature that Microsoft (and other venders) added in ASP.NET 3.5’s version of ASP.NET AJAX (and other frameworks). By encapsulating the JSON response within a parent object, the framework helps protect against a "JSON hacking" XSS vulnerability.

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx

From the article:

> ASP.NET and WCF JSON service endpoints
>   actually wrap their JSON in an object
>   with the “d” property as I wrote about
>   a while back. While it might seem odd
>   to have to go through this property to
>   get access to your data, this
>   awkwardness is eased by the fact that
>   the generated client proxies for these
>   services strip the “d” property so the
>   end-user doesn’t need to know it was
>   ever there.
>
> With ASP.NET MVC (and other similar
>   frameworks), a significant number of
>   developers are not using client
>   generated proxies (we don’t have them)
>   but instead using jQuery and other
>   such libraries to call into these
>   methods, making the “d” fix kind of
>   awkward.